# Google Map vs. Cluster Manager: onCameraChangeListener deprecated

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer, android-maps-utils

I've got an Android app with about 500-1000 markers. I am using the ClusterManager from the [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering) to cluster these markers.

In the latest Play Services update Google changed the listener model of the Google Map. The `OnCameraChangeListener` is marked as deprecated now. Instead there are four new listeners (`OnCameraIdleListener, OnCameraMoveListener, OnCameraMoveStartedListener`,`OnCameraMoveCanceledListener`).

Since that update my app is incredibly slow. It stucks on moving/zooming the map, the clustering process is laggy and needs some seconds.

I thought this behavior is maybe linked to the changes in the listener model. Therefore I tried to replace the `addOnCameraChangeListener(clustermanager)` function with the new `addOnCameraIdleListener(clustermanager)`. Unfortunately this is not working as the `ClusterManager` does not implement the necessary Interface.

And this is where it gets strange, because the current version (0.4.3) of the [`ClusterManager`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java) on GitHub does implement that Interface. So it should work.

I'm importing the ClusterManager using Gradle:

`compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3`

but my local version of the `ClusterManager` still seems to be an old one which implements the old `OnCameraChangeListener`.

So what is wrong here? 
Is this a misbehavior of Gradle? 
Has anybody an idea how to fix this issue? 
And is there anybody else whose Google Map / Clusterer is slow and laggy since the last Play Services update?

I appreciate any help. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use gooleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager); instead of googleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(mClusterManager);

You can to search for the source code of ClusterManager and you will see that ClusterManager implements the new OnCameraIdleListener.

Also you need to update to new android-maps-utils:0.4.4 (compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4')

Good luck and vote up... ;-)

Comment: It works fine now the 4.4 version of android-maps-utils.
When I posted this question only the 4.3 version was available via Gradle (4.4 was just on GitHub). Seems like someone made it available now. So, thanks Max, and thanks "someone". ;)